# Laravel Carbon get start + end of last week?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have laravel carbon for get start + end of current week :

```
$startofcurrentweek =Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(); //2020-02-17 00:00:00
$endofcurrentweek =Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(); //2020-02-23 23:59:59
```

How To get Start of Last Week  using carbon ,... So i can get,

```
$startoflasttweek  = 2020-02-10 00:00:00
$endoflastweek  = 2020-02-16 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subtract 7 days to the start of current week or subtract 7 days from now and get the start of the week.

```
$startOfCurrentWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(); 

$startOfLastWeek  = $startOfCurrentWeek->copy()->subDays(7);
$startOfLastWeek  = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->startOfWeek();
```

And the same to get the end of the last week.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to answers above but more clear:

```
$startOfLastWeek = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->startOfWeek();
$endOfLastWeek = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->endOfWeek();
```

1. It substracts 7 days from the current time (which goes to the last week) and **startOfWeek** gets the **starting** date and time of that week.
2. It substracts 7 days from the current time (which goes to the last week) and **endOfWeek** gets the **ending** date and time of that week.

**Result/Example?**

If current time is **2022-04-27 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)** then it results as follows:

1. 2022-04-18 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
2. 2022-04-24 23:59:59.999999 UTC (+00:00)

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Porloscerros is correct but need a little bit fix:

```
$startOfCurrentWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(); 

$startOfLastWeek  = $startOfCurrentWeek->copy()->subDays(7);

$startOfLastWeek  = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->startOfWeek()->endOfDay();
```

with ->***endOfDay()*** This will return 23:59:59 9999.99
instead of 00:00:00 (beginning of the day)

or you can use ***->endOfWeek()*** for the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek();
```

to get the start of last week and use

```
now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek();
```

to obtain the end of last week's date.

It's just like doing `now()->subDays(7)->startOfWeek();` or `now()->subDays(7)->endOfWeek();`